# Read the value of an attribute of a Core Data entity

Tags: swift, core-data

I'm trying to read the value of an attribute (called 'name') of an entity (called 'List'), stored in a Core Data database. The issue that I have is that it says that the value of that attribute is nil, which should be a String.

[image: My data model]

My code for retrieving all List-entities is as follows:

```
container?.performBackgroundTask { [weak self] context in
    self?.wordLists = try! List.all(in: context)
    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
        print("Main queue available, reloading tableview.")
        self?.wordListSelector.reloadData()
    })
}

class func all(in context: NSManagedObjectContext) throws -> [List] {
    let listRequest: NSFetchRequest<List> = List.fetchRequest()
    do {
        let list = try context.fetch(listRequest)
        print(list)
        return list
    } catch {
        print("error")
        throw error
    }
}
```

This prints:

```
[<__Words.List: 0x6000000937e0> (entity: List; id: 0xd00000000004000c <x-coredata://999D0158-64BD-44FD-A0B1-AB4EC03B9386/List/p1> ; data: <fault>), <__Words.List: 0x600000093a60> (entity: List; id: 0xd00000000008000c <x-coredata://999D0158-64BD-44FD-A0B1-AB4EC03B9386/List/p2> ; data: <fault>), <__Words.List: 0x600000093ab0> (entity: List; id: 0xd0000000000c000c <x-coredata://999D0158-64BD-44FD-A0B1-AB4EC03B9386/List/p3> ; data: <fault>)]
```

Which shows me that there should be 3 lists in the database, which is as expected.

[image: Core Date Editor: showing that I have indeed 3 Lists in my database]

I have created a variable like this:

```
var wordLists: [List] = [] {
    didSet {
        print("Detected wordList update, waiting for main queue.")
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            print("Main queue available, reloading tableview.")
            self.wordListSelector.reloadData()
        })
    }
}
```

This variable holds the List-entities that I retrieved by calling that all() function which I mentioned previously.

The following two methods will fill my TableView:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print("numberOfRowsInSection: \(wordLists.count).")
    return wordLists.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier = "CategoryCell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath)

    print("cellForRowAt: \(indexPath.row) has name \(wordLists[indexPath.row].name).")
    cell.textLabel?.text = wordLists[indexPath.row].name

    return cell
}
```

This prints the following:

```
Detected wordList update, waiting for main queue.
Main queue available, reloading tableview.
numberOfRowsInSection: 3.
cellForRowAt: 0 has name nil.
cellForRowAt: 1 has name nil.
cellForRowAt: 2 has name nil.
```

Why is the name nil? Is this because the data is still 'faulted'? By viewing topics online I thought that Core Data automaticly unfaulted its data when you try to access it. What am I doing wrong?

Edit:

If I change the didset to the following:

```
var wordLists: [List] = [] {
    didSet {
        print("Wordlist was updated.")
        for wordList in wordLists {
            print(wordList)
            print(wordList.name)
        }
    }
}
```

It does print the names (Optional("nameofitem1")). In the cellForRowAt it still prints 'nil'.

Comment: I would **not** use the `didSet` observer for a data source array. Reload the table view after fetching the data.

Comment: Okay I'll change that, good observation:) Except for that, any ideas why I'm getting a 'nil' value instead of the actual name though?

Comment: Please can you show the code where you actually populate the WordLists array?  You are right, CD should automatically fire the fault on the List objects when you access the attributes.  But it can fail to do this if you are accessing them from the wrong thread.  The fact that your `didSet` uses dispatch async suggests you might indeed be mixing threads.

Comment: I have added the code where I populate the wordList array. I have also changed the didSet to a forloop. This forloop does print the names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you do looks like a good job for the NSFetchedResultsController. That will also help with the threading you might mix up as suggested in the comments. There is really good documentation on the [NSFetchedResultsController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsfetchedresultscontroller)

Comment: Ah thanks! I've implemented the NSFetchResultsController and that works fine.